# Regasm installs shell extension correctly, but heat-generated WXS does not, writes to different registry path

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

I wrote a shell extension (item in explorer's file context menu), and used WiX's `heat` to create an MSI from the DLL.

**PROBLEM:** Installing the MSI does not make the context menu item appear.
In contrast, running `Regasm.exe my.dll /codebase` makes the item appear.

`heat` writes registry keys into `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`, while
`Regasm` writes registry keys into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\`.

I could modify the `heat`-generated WXS to write to the same registry path as `Regasm`, but [MSDN suggests HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120299/226958) some users are not be able to write into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE... is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKCR` is an alias for `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\` when your MSI package is per-machine. The easiest way to ensure pre-machine package is to set the `InstallScope` on the `Package` element:

```
<Wix>
  <Product ...>
     <Package InstallScope='perMachine' />
```

Comment: Unfortunately the file context menu item still does not appear.

Comment: I've been searching for how to do this for ages, and have been using find-replace on my heat-generated fragments for months to guarantee that it is written into HKLM rather than HKCR. This is the perfect solution!