# test if com dll is registered using its path

Tags: c#, c, windows, com

hi i got a com/activeX and i want to know if its registered. I know NOTHING about the file except it is a com/dll that needs to be checked.
[How to check if a COM component (EXE/DLL file) is registered or not (using .NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491909/how-to-check-if-com-componentexe-dll-is-registered-or-not-using-net)

[How to check COM dll is registered or not with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966508/how-to-check-com-dll-is-registered-or-not-with-c)

and so on tell me to search based on guid. but I failed to find explanation of hwo to find GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know at least one of its CLSID guids then you cannot find out.  Nor could you ever *use* the component so testing for something you can't use isn't terribly useful.

If this is an ActiveX component then you can learn more about it by looking at its type library.  Which is usually embedded in the DLL as a resource.  Check that first with Visual Studio's File + Open + File, select the DLL.  If you see a TYPELIB resource then you're ahead.  From the Visual Studio Command Line prompt, run oleview.exe.  File + View Typelib and select the DLL.  You'll see the interfaces and coclasses defined in the type library.  Pick one of the guids of a coclass to test for.

Another way to find out is by using Regedit.exe and use Edit + Find.  Type the name of the DLL.  When it finds a key named "LocalServer32" then you found the CLSID key.

Another way to find out is by running a program that uses the component and observe the trace produced by SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see the program searching the CLSID key and read the LocalServer32 key.  With the disadvantage that the tool tends to drown you in data.